# Can you do demand/sales forecasting using data with no significant correlation?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, acf-pacf

I am  playing around with a sales data period January 2016 - July 2017 from a company, after using ACF and PACF, this is the result:

ACF:

[image: Autocorrelation Function]

PACF:

[image: Partial Autocorrelation Function]

I am currently trying to do a sales forecasting based on this data. I understand that this means my data is a random series data, but is it possible to do forecasting based on a random data?

Is there any forecasting method to do this?

Comment: practically, no.  Your best "forecast" will probably be the long-term mean.